# Importing module in a function when returning

Tags: python, python-import

I've being searching on how to do this, but I could not find if there is a solution. I thought `__import__`? But I still couldn't manage to figure it out.
For example:

```
>>> def combs(s = []):
...     from itertools import combinations
...     return [list(combinations(s, 2))]
...
>>> lst = ["A","B",'C']
>>> print(combs(lst))
[[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]]
>>>
```

I'm curious if something like this could be done?

```
def combs(s = []):
    return [list(combinations(s, 2))]__import__(itertools, list)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is "this" that should be done? And why would you want to import something on return?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Just curious if there is a way to do this, What I am refering to "this" is the code `__import__(itertools, list)`. If it's possible to implement something like that on return.

Comment: Why would that be any different from importing it properly, and returning that? Except being much less readable.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I guess, it wouldn't be, I was looking if there is a possible way to do it.
@JohnColeman Oh, well. I thought `__import__` is for something like this,

Comment: I still don't understand what you actually want to import or what you want to return (but I still don't think you're trying to do something reasonable).

Comment: @BlueMonday. Try: `return list(__import__('itertools').combinations(s, 2))`. But that is really nasty, so please don't actually do it ;-)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Could post it as answer? And why it's nasty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to achieve a dynamic import in your example:

```
def combs(s = []):
    return list(__import__('itertools').combinations(s, 2))
```

NB: the python docs for [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) state that:

> This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python programming

Many Pythonistas would prefer an explicit import (as in your original example), and would probably consider excessive use of `__import__` to be a bit of a code smell.

Comment: I see, I wouldn't use it, I wanted to know if it is possible to achieve something like that. Thanks.